# Association Bonus on Triggering Site

Tags: discussion, association-bonus

Today I got to 200 reputation points on Stack Overflow. I knew this would give me the association bonus on all the other Stack Exchange sites I'm on. I was surprised and puzzled though that it gave me an association bonus on Stack Overflow as well. So it's like you reach 200 and you're automatically advanced to 300. Is this the way it's supposed to be? I guess it could be why I can't say I've ever seen anyone around on SO that has points in the 200s.

Comment: Yes, it is. You get the bonus on *all* sites. The triggering site is no exception.